# Creating Multiple Data Table for list of Records using LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, lightning-datatable, datatable

Can anyone tell me how do I create multiple data table using single lightning data table in my html and iterating over with template for each with the list ?

I am looking at something like this:

[image]

Please note all the information of table 1 and table 2 including columns,data values is in a JSON that I would receiving via apex.

I tried with this but looks like I am missing something here are the JS and HTML files:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

const everythingData = [];
const alldata = [];
const data1 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Billy Simonns', age: 40, email: 'billy@salesforce.com' }];
const data2 = [
    { id: 2, name: 'Kelsey Denesik', age: 35, email: 'kelsey@salesforce.com' }
];

alldata.push(data1);
alldata.push(data2);

const allColumns = [];


const columns = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'name' },
    {
        label: 'Age',
        fieldName: 'age',
        type: 'number',
        sortable: true,
        cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' },
    },
    { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'email', type: 'email' },
];

const columns1 = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'name' },
    {
        label: 'Age',
        fieldName: 'age',
        type: 'number',
        sortable: true,
        cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' },
    },
    { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'email', type: 'email' },
];

allColumns.push(columns);
allColumns.push(columns1);

everythingData.push(allColumns);
everythingData.push(alldata);

export default class DemoApp extends LightningElement {
    alldata = alldata;
    allColumns = allColumns;
    everythingData = everythingData;
    defaultSortDirection = 'asc';
    sortDirection = 'asc';
    sortedBy;

    // Used to sort the 'Age' column
    sortBy(field, reverse, primer) {
        const key = primer
            ? function (x) {
                  return primer(x[field]);
              }
            : function (x) {
                  return x[field];
              };

        return function (a, b) {
            a = key(a);
            b = key(b);
            return reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
        };
    }

    onHandleSort(event) {
        const { fieldName: sortedBy, sortDirection } = event.detail;
        const cloneData = [...this.data];

        cloneData.sort(this.sortBy(sortedBy, sortDirection === 'asc' ? 1 : -1));
        this.data = cloneData;
        this.sortDirection = sortDirection;
        this.sortedBy = sortedBy;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
<template for:each={everythingData.allColumns} for:item="acc">
  
        <template for:each={everythingData.alldata} for:item="def">
<lightning-datatable
        key-field={acc.def.id}
        columns={acc}
        data={def}
        hide-checkbox-column
        default-sort-direction={defaultSortDirection}
        sorted-direction={sortDirection}
        sorted-by={sortedBy}
        onsort={onHandleSort}>
</lightning-datatable>
</template>
    
    </template>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put all of the data that you want to be individualized into the data together. From there, you need to use those individual variables to render the tables.

```
const tables = [
  {
    id: '1',
    columns: [
      { label: "Name", fieldName: "name" },
      {
        label: "Age",
        fieldName: "age",
        type: "number",
        sortable: true,
        cellAttributes: { alignment: "left" },
      },
      { label: "Email", fieldName: "email", type: "email" },
    ],
    data: [
      { id: 1, name: "Billy Simonns", age: 40, email: "billy@salesforce.com" },
    ],
    defaultSortDirection: 'asc',
    sortedBy: '',
    sortedDirection: 'asc',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    columns: [
      { label: "Name", fieldName: "name" },
      {
        label: "Age",
        fieldName: "age",
        type: "number",
        sortable: true,
        cellAttributes: { alignment: "left" },
      },
      { label: "Email", fieldName: "email", type: "email" },
    ],
    data: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Kelsey Denesik",
        age: 35,
        email: "kelsey@salesforce.com",
      },
    ],
    defaultSortDirection: 'asc',
    sortedBy: 'Name',
    sortedDirection: 'asc'
  },
];
```

---

```
onHandleSort(event) {
    const { fieldName: sortedBy, sortDirection } = event.detail;
    const tableId = event.target.dataset.tableId;
    console.log(tableId);
    const table = tables.find((entry)=>entry.id===tableId);
    const cloneData = [...table.data];

    cloneData.sort(this.sortBy(sortedBy, sortDirection === 'asc' ? 1 : -1));
    table.data = cloneData;
    table.sortedDirection = sortDirection;
    table.sortedBy = sortedBy;
}
```

---

```
<template>
    <div for:each={tables} for:item="table" class="slds-m-bottom_small" key={table.id}>
        <lightning-datatable key-field="id" columns={table.columns} data={table.data} hide-checkbox-column
            default-sort-direction={table.defaultSortDirection} sorted-direction={table.sortedDirection} sorted-by={sortedBy}
            data-table-id={table.id} onsort={onHandleSort}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </div>
</template>
```

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/h9t29xkKib12f41oMSfx/src/app.js?p=stories).

Comment: Wow that was quick !. I was scratching my head since yesterday for this. 

Thanks a lot @sfdcfox I never new we can use for each, for item in lightning data table. It does not show that these can be used even in the documentation.

Comment: @Ajay `for:each` and the like are HTML directives that can be used on virtually every element, aside from the top-level template tag. If what I did here makes you feel uneasy, though, you can wrap your table in a template. I just prefer to avoid such fluff.

Comment: In between each table can I have some spacing ? like it just piles up one table on the other but ideally I'd like two different tables with spacing.

Comment: @Ajay Yes, for that, you'll need some margin, and to get that to work correctly, you will need a wrapper element (in my example, a div). I'll edit that in for you.

Comment: Thanks a ton mate!. Seriously You are a champ. Salesforce is actually gifted to have you. You made my day!.

Comment: @Ajay No problem. This looks like a lot, but it was really just a bunch of copy-paste. Well-written questions are easy to answer that way. 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139519/discussion-between-ajay-and-sfdcfox).

Comment: Hey @sfdcfox, the solution was good. But I am not forming this constant in this child LWC. This constant is coming as a response from a Apex method that is being sent to this Child LWC from parent LWC. How do I do that ? I used getter and setter to get the value from parent LWC. However when I assign to this constant in Child LWC. It does not work.

Comment: What I did was declared the constant format at the top of the LWC Like this

const tables = [
{
Id: '',
columns: [
{}
],
data: [
{}
],
Name:''
}

];


Then I iterate over the Serialized JSON that is coming from the Apex method and assign all the data to this constant.

what happened on the UI was datatable was coming up but there is no data . However in the console log I can clearly see all of the table data.